# Sum CSV columns and save CSV result in varchar column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I Want to sum Counters column to get summed in Hour table then later on Day table

How can i get this expected result ,How can i start with it ?, i know using substring_index & loop in store procedure I can achieve expected result, but it is complex as my Length per entity is different & summation per entity and storing it in same format is tedious for me. thanks in advance

Minute table (Here I receive each minute new counter value entries per entity)

```
Timestamp   Entity    Counters(varchar)
 13:01:00    ABC       1,0,0,1,3,0... N-length of counters 
 13:01:00    XYZ       12,0,0,0,0,4... K-length of counters
 13:02:00    ABC       1,0,2,1,0,0... N
 13:02:00    XYZ       1,4,2,0,0,0....K
 13:03:00    ABC       0,0,0,0,0,1... N
 13:03:00    XYZ       0,2,2,0,0,0....K
 . . 
 . 
 14:01:00
 14:02:00
 ..
```

Result Expected

Hour table (Group by Entity and Hour)

```
Timestamp   Entity    Counters 
 13:00:00    ABC       2,0,2,2,3,1...  N (sum of all counters within that Hour for respective entity)
 13:00:00    XYZ       13,6,4,0,0,4....K
 14:00:00    ABC       0,0,0,0,0,0... N (sum of 14th hour) 
 14:00:00    XYZ       0,0,0,0,0,0... K (sum of 14th hour)
 ... 
 .
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Oh dear - that's a terrible way to store data and yes a tricky proc is the way to go

Comment: unfortunately i am receiving data from client in minute table , i want to save it as history make summary in hour and day tables

Comment: 'unfortunately i am receiving data from client in minute table' - 1 row per minute? or as in published data? If the latter then refer to my previous comment

Comment: N entity rows per minute

Answer (score 0):

Your primary focus should be on fixing your data model.  What is wrong?  Here are some things:

- Storing multiple values in a column is a bad idea.
- Storing numbers as strings is a bad idea.
- SQL has pretty lousy string processing functionality.

Each value should be a separate row in another table.  Although this takes more space, it is probably much more efficient as well.  Inserting a new row in a table is typically much faster than updating a row.

Assuming you are stuck with your data model because of someone else's really, really, really bad data modeling decision, you can approach this with brute force.

That starts by determining the maximum number of values in the row.  Then you can extract each one individually and add them together:

```
select t.*,
       ( (substring_index(counters, ',', 1) + 0) +
         (case when counters like '%,%' then sub string_index(substring_index(counters, ',', 2), ',', -1) + 0 else 0 end) +
         (case when counters like '%,%,%' then sub string_index(substring_index(counters, ',', 3), ',', -1) + 0 else 0 end) +
         (case when counters like '%,%,%,%' then sub string_index(substring_index(counters, ',', 4), ',', -1) + 0 else 0 end) +
         . . . 
        ) as total
from t;
```